# GUID but not really a GUID

Tags: asp.net-identity

The identity manager users Guid but the database type is still string? This obviously make sense if you are wanting to use a database that doesnt support uniqueidentifier type.. but what if we need to use GUID?

Is there any way we can modify the database type to be uniqueidentifier? I am successfully renaming my table to "User" but the same trick doesnt work with HasColumnType to use GUID

i have tried:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give example of DB, which doesn't support the GUID type ?

Comment: older versions of Access? or mySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be a direct solution to your problem, but at least there is light at the end of the tunnel: The preview of Asp.net Identity 2.0.0-alpha1 [has recently been announced](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx).

One of the new features is the extensibility of the primary key type for users and roles:

> In 1.0 the type of PK for Users and Roles was strings. This means when the ASP.NET Identity system was persisted in Sql Server using Entity Framework, we were using nvarchar. There were lots of discussions around this default implementation on Stack Overflow and based on the incoming feedback, we have provided an extensibility hook where you can specify what should be the PK of your Users and Roles table. This extensibility hook is particularly useful if you are migrating your application and the application was storing UserIds are GUIDs or ints.

You can read more about the release and how to get it on the announcement post: [Announcing preview of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity 2.0.0-alpha1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx)